# What are the most useful things to log when writing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, logging

I am writing up some code in Javascript/JQuery that involves some confusing DOM operations, or at least they are to me because I'm relatively inexperienced.

I try to help myself by doing a couple of `console.log()`s, but the thing is if you just log a DOM element you get useless information, mostly it's `object Object`.

I was wondering what the most usefull generic attributes of a HTML element are so that I could easily follow what the script is doing?

Comment: What browser are you using that `console.log(domEl)` yields `object Object`? Chrome does this: http://cl.ly/image/2f0O1Y2i3L1G

Comment: @wirey, nope FF. Yes and I do use Firebug. It's supposed to contain references when logging JQuery objects, but it doesn't...

Comment: It's useful to label your logs, for example: `console.log("theVarName",theVarName)` so that you know what produced the log.

Comment: I'm not seeing why this question has been downvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering what the most usefull generic attributes of a HTML element are so that I could easily follow what the script is doing?

Don't use logging for debugging. Use a debugger for debugging. Even IE (8 and up) has a debugger built in. If you want to know what the code is doing, there's *nothing* that substitutes for stepping through the code in the debugger and examining your various variables and such as you go.

But answering your specific question, I'd say I'd want to see the DOM element's `tagName`, `className` (e.g, class[es]), and `id` (if any).

Comment: @Mario De Schaepmeester: You've said elsewhere you're using Firebug, so you have a reasonable debugger available to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use chrome when inspecting the console log, the objects actually come through so  you can expand and see all of their properties.  Keep in mind some of the older browsers, IE8 or 7, do not support console.log and it will throw a javascript error.

Comment: i am using firefox though.

Comment: Then use Firebug (which you are).  Just use the debugger and forget about the print statements...

Comment: @jahroy it's what I usually do, I just wanted to try a different approach for what I'm doing as I thought it could be faster.

Comment: I wouldn't disregard the value of the the log completely, as it does server a purpose

Comment: We recently implemented a Servlet that logs messages from JavaScript to our log4j log files.  It's pretty sweet.